# Pass data from side-menu to main scree in 'react-native-navigation'

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, side-menu

Is there a way to pass data from side-menu to central (main) screen in wix-react-native-navigation? I have some calculations in the central screen and a switch in the side-menu to change units from inch to mm. Now I want side-menu to pass data to central screen that switch was flicked and then units should be changed from inch to mm or the other way.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using Redux? you could save the changes made in the side menu in your reducer and access the data.

Comment: I thought Redux may be an overkill for the app but if it's the only option I will try it later. Thanks

Comment: Works great. States from both screens are accessible under the reducer.